# Image of a dense set

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Is the image of a dense set under an isometric operator is again dense set?
i.e.,

Given two Hilbert spaces $X, Y$.

If   $T:X\to Y$ is an isometric operator and $S$ is a dense span subset of $X$, is it true that $T(S)$ is a dense span subset of $T(X)$?.

Comment: I suggest to change the question into "is $T(S)$ a dense span subset of $T(X)$?". Otherwise, if $T$ is not onto, the answer is trivially "no".

Comment: Yes, you're right, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking of an isometry onto $Y$ then it is true because any homeomorphism maps dense sets to dense sets. Otherwise it is certainly not true. Let $T: l^{2} \to l^{2}$ be defined by $T(x_1,x_2,...) =(0,x_1,x_2,...)$ and Take $S=X$.  Then the closure of the range of $T$ is $\{(x_n):x_1=0\}$.